# SQL paging with non-fixed-length page size

Tags: sql

The table is simple: It has 2 columns, `id` and `type`. The `type` can be 1 or 2.
Now I want the first 10 entries with `type` 1, in a sequence ordered by `id`, and if there are `type` 2 entries somewhere in between then they should be included in the result set too. What is the SQL query?

It's basically paging but the number of rows per page can vary so can't use OFFSET and LIMIT.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I was just looking for general ideas, irrespective of any specific DBMS. SQL is standardized so all DBMS have similar ways of doing things. The example i used is also a generalized simplified case which can be useful for many similar scenarios.

Comment: "*SQL is standardized*" - in theory that is true, but in reality things might be very different depending on the DBMS you are using. Especially if efficiency or more complex conditions are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use CTE to make request for type 1 records once and then union with records of Type 2.

I selected only 5 rows to use less test data.

```
create table #TEST (Id int, Type int)
insert into #TEST
select  1,2 union
select  2,1 union
select  3,1 union
select  4,2 union
select  5,2 union
select  6,1 union
select  7,1 union
select  8,2 union
select  9,1 union
select  10,1 union
select  11,2 union
select  12,2 union
select  13,1 union
select  14,1 union
select  15,1

go

with list1 (Id, Type)
as 
(
    select *
    from #Test
    where Type = 1
    order by Id
    offset 0 rows fetch next 5 rows only
)

select * 
from list1 

union all 

select * 
from #Test
where Type = 2 and Id > (select min(Id) from list1) and Id < (select max(Id) from list1)
order by Id
```

Comment: Thx, both answers suggest combining 2 queries, and using info from the result of the first query for the second query. I gave this a tick because a union to me "feels" more efficient than @JBrooks's double insertion into a temp table idea.

Answer (score 1):

Should look something like this:

```
DECLARE @limit int = 25, @offset int = 10

DECLARE @ret TABLE (
ID INT,
TYPEID INT)

INSERT INTO @ret
SELECT Id, TypeId     
FROM Logs
WHERE TypeId = 1
ORDER BY id
LIMIT @limit OFFSET @offset;


INSERT INTO @ret
SELECT id, TypeId     
FROM Logs
WHERE TypeId = 2
AND ID BETWEEN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @ret) AND (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM @ret)

SELECT *
FROM @ret
ORDER BY ID
```

You could collapse this into a single SQL statement using a UNION, but it would have to query for the same data (limit and offset) more than once.